# How does the Chrome debugger call stack work, particularly the naming?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, backbone.js

I would assume that the call stack names functions and it looks like it tries to, but they are strange names.  For example while stepping into Backbone fetch(), I get this.

[image]

`_.extend.fetch` I'm assuming refers to `Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch`

This function was called from `Backbone.View.extend.initialize` which I'm assuming refers to `Backbone.View.prototype.initialize`

Why is the naming so strange if not inaccurate?

Answer (score 0):

The prototype methods are added to the `Collection` with [`_.extend` from the underscore library](http://underscorejs.org/#extend), i.e. in line 633 in the latest revision:

> https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/628590bac02b7eb7ef6590773fdb90422e77b913/backbone.js#L633

It's not immediately clear how Chrome turned this into `_.extend.fetch`, but this probably has a lot to do with it. It appears to me that `fetch` was part of a literal object that was passed to `_.extend`, so maybe that's the derivation.

A lot of libraries define objects with this weird extend syntax using anonymous objects, which probably confuses the debugger quite a bit. However, it's hard to succinctly assign properties to the prototype without something like Coffeescript, for example.

Comment: it's not the syntax in the code used that is weird.  It is the naming conventions of the call stack in the debugger that I find weird.  Using _.extend to add object properties is pretty standard.